# ASEventSourcesTable not being populated

Tags: appfabric

On some developer PC's at my organisation (which have local installs of AppFabric server and the underlying monitoring database), AppFabric is failing to populate the ASEventSourcesTable table, therefore resulting in no events arriving in the ASWcfEventsTable table.

If I manually insert what is required in the ASEventSourcesTable table (going off another AppFabric install etc where ASEventSourcesTable is populated automatically), then events are arriving and are visible through the dashboard (therefore suggesting all the moving parts are working - service, sql agent etc).

Any ideas on what would be stopping AppFabric 'parsing' IIS to determine what is a valid event source? Something in the config?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the process is a bit different. The Event Collection service (installed on the hosting server) captures the WCF ETW event data and writes it to the staging table (ASStagingTable) in the monitoring database.A SQL Agent job continuously runs and checks for new event records in the staging table, parses the event data, and moves it to the long-term storage WCF event table.

So, Check first the ASStagingTable and that every appfabric monitoring client have access to the monitoring db (network and connectionstring). Event logs can also give you more informations.

I would highly suggest you read this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/appfabric-items-to-check-when-configuring-appfabric-monitoring.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the response - however as I mentioned in my question, the events are visible in the dashboard once the ASEventSourcesTable is populated (which contains the possible services that can provide events, i.e. is used to associate the events correctly with the appropriate service). For some PC's running AppFabric, this table is not being populated - if I manually insert values (e.g. insert a service emitting events) - then events as you say arrive in the appropriate staging table etc